# meaning of "doom somebody"?

Tags: meaning

To figure out ["alternate" vs. "substitute"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251422/116345), I went through quite a lot of posts which include [Usage of alternate vs alternative with "equally"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/95890/116345)

> doing something is equally alternate to **dooming yourself**

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/doom)

> doom: to make someone or something certain to do or experience something unpleasant, or to make something bad certain to happen

With the definition above, I don’t really understand the meaning of the quotation.

I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22doom%20somebody%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=define%20%22doom%20somebody%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12238j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but can't get any definition or explanation.

What does that mean? Is it natural to say "doom somebody"?

Comment: Judging from some of the comments, the people who answered that question don't understand it either. However, _doom_ as a verb means _condemn_.

Comment: If you swallow poison you have doomed yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is natural to say "doom someone/something".

[From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doom)

> **doom** verb
> *doomed; dooming; dooms
>
> Definition of doom (Entry 2 of 2)*
> *transitive verb*
> **1:** to give judgment against : ***CONDEMN***
> **2a:** to fix the fate of : ***DESTINE***
> *felt he was doomed to a life of loneliness*
> **b:** to make certain the failure or destruction of
> *the scandal doomed her chances for election*

To put it simply, it means to cause to be sure that bad things will happen.

Many examples use passive voice:

> **He was doomed** to a life of loneliness. (by...?)

That sentence omits the cause, so let's add one in.

> **He was doomed** to a life of loneliness by never leaving his house.

We can easily turn that into using active voice:

> Choosing to never leave his house **doomed him** to a life of loneliness.